# Using the shapebuilder tool to make shading on a donut. Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, cs6, fill

I am following a youtube tutorial (not a speed art vid) and have become stuck at the shapebuilder tool step. Basically there is the purple stroke on a seperate layer. The pink fill is on its own layer. The pink fill has been duplicated and offset to the left.

[image]

In the tutorial the man pastes the fill that is NOT offset in front from my understanding. The man then goes to the shapebuilder tool and subtracts as below.

[image]

[image]

The below is a screenshot of the result that happens when I try and follow this step.

[image]

The end result is some shading to add some depth to the image see below.

[image]

Comment: @Scott yes that makes sense and it worked I must of missed that when I was following the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting all the pink fills.

You need to leave the *base fill* alone and only work with 2 - the pink, and an offset. It *appears* as though you **aren't** pasting an extra, non-offset, fill as you describe the tutorial doing.

In short -- you should have 3 pink shapes, and use Shape Builder on *only* 2 of those.

[image]

Color texture at the end of the animation is merely due to gif compression and unintentional.